# Singletons (sets with single element): what's special about them?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, category-theory

I am asking a broad question. I don't need precise definition. I just want to get "big picture" of why singletons considered like something important, especially when it comes down to category theory?

Why, for example, 2-elements sets are not that special?

Comment: In category theory (especially the categories of sets, and of topological / metric spaces), the defining property of singleton sets is that they are [terminal objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects). Whether that makes them special enough is up to you.

Comment: Secondly note that the elements of set $X$ correspond with arrows $\cdot\to X$ where $\cdot$ stands for a singleton. So $X$ corresponds with the homset $\mathbf{Set}(\cdot,X)$.That gives possibilities to "catch" the theory of sets in the theory of categories.

Comment: 2-element sets *are* rather special in the category of sets as any can be used as the subobject classifier.

Comment: I am curious why you think that singletons are considered more important than 2-element sets.  Where did you get this impression from?  (There are ways in which it is true, but if there is some particular context which prompted your question then we will be able to resolve your question better if you provide that context.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citing the comments as an answer:

- In category theory (especially the categories of sets, and of topological / metric spaces), the defining property of singleton sets is that they are [terminal objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects):

  > There is exactly one function from any set to a one-element set.
- Secondly note that the elements of set $X$ correspond with arrows $\ast\to X$ where $\ast$ stands for a singleton. So $X$ corresponds with the homset $\mathcal Set(\ast,X)$. That gives possibilities to "catch" the theory of sets in the theory of categories. In other words

  > For any set $X$, its elements are in a natural one-to-one correspondence with functions $\ast\to X$ where $\ast$ is a one element set.
- 2-element sets are also special in the category of sets, as these can be used as *subobject classifier*:

  > For any set $X$, its subsets are in a natural one-to-one correspondence with functions $X\to T$ where $T$ is a two element set.